# Android Studio IDE issue (font/encoding: abcd -> cdef)

Tags: android-studio, encoding, utf-8, ide, custom-font

Installed Android Studio maybe week ago. All was great.
Then yesterday have tried to open it. Something strange happened: all english letters are shifted right in alphabet (abcd -> cdef).

[Loaded IDE start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g45tG.png)

It reminds me of encoding problems (I use ukrainian windows, but another apps (Latin / Cyrillic) are working without problems).

Have checked Language and Regional settings, but everything is fine with it (as I think). Tried to change IDE encoding to UTF-8 too - nothing changed.

Encoding error detector site(online-decoder) gives me nothing... Searching on abcd to cdef and other encoding problems too... Have not found anything similar, but maybe i have tried to search in wrong direction. At least now i have "encrypted" IDE, and can spend some time to get familiar with this "language" :D

How to solve this?

System:
 - Win7 64 bit.
 - Android Studio 2.3.1

I think that it can be because i have changed system font and maybe something gone wrong. Will try to change it back to original.

**EDIT: After changing system font back to original [All is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OSlN.png). But anyway that is strange that most of the apps supports ISOCPEUR, and Android Studio doesn't.**